# In Java HashMap, how many nodes can a red-black-tree node have at most before untreeify because it's too small in deletion?

Tags: java, hashmap, red-black-tree

Java doc of the method removeTreeNode of TreeNode in Java HashMap says

> If the current tree appears to have too few nodes, the bin is converted back to a plain bin. (The test triggers somewhere between 2 and 6 nodes, depending on tree structure)

In the code,

```
   if (root == null || root.right == null ||
                (rl = root.left) == null || rl.left == null) {
                tab[index] = first.untreeify(map);  // too small
                return;
   }
```

which means when either the root, left child of root, right child of root, left child of left child of root is null, the tree is considered too small and need untreeifyng.

The question is, how many node can the tree have at most, before untreeifyng?
the java doc says 6.
But I think it can have 10 nodes, like the one below:

[image]

The leaf nodes are black and null, and not drawn in the picture.

If I'm wrong, where am I wrong?

Comment: I don't have time to look through the code but my guess would be that these trees are balanced trees. That's how they can get away with only checking `root.left.left == null`.

Comment: But my sample tree is perfectly black-balanced.